# Strange pattern in standard deviation confidence interval estimation via bootstrapping

Tags: r, confidence-interval, standard-deviation, bootstrap

I wanted to estimate confidence interval for standard deviation for some data. R code looks like follows:

```
library(boot)
sd_boot <- function (x, ind) {                
        res <- sd(x$ReadyChange[ind], na.rm = TRUE)
        return(res)            
}
data_boot <- boot::boot(data, statistic = sd_boot, R = 10000)
plot(data_boot)
```

And I've got the next plot: [image]

I'm stuck with interpreting this histogram of bootstraps correctly. Every other set of similar data shows normal distributions of bootstrap estimates... But not this. By the way, this is actual raw data:

```
> data$ReadyChange
 [1] 27.800000  8.985046 11.728021  8.830856  5.738600 12.028310  7.771528  9.208924 11.778611  6.024259  5.969931  6.063484  4.915764
[14] 12.027639  9.111146 13.898171 12.921377  6.916667 10.764479  6.875000 12.875000  7.017917  9.750000  7.921782 12.911551  6.000000
```

Can you please help me with interpretation of this bootstrap pattern?

Comment: The code's not transparent to all of us! What's the role of `ind`? Does it interfere with the sampling here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results even copying and pasting the code. I get a very normally distributed histogram.

Comment: @nick-cox, please refer to the 'boot' R package manual. 'ind' stands for 'indexes', that is the random indexes of data vector for bootstrapping the original data. This is standard 'boot' package code, that seems not so clear at first glance.

Comment: @jwimberley , there was a wrong data vector... Thank you for your time for discovering it. Actual data is in post below EDIT.

Comment: pattern confirmed for new data. My guess is that it is caused by the datapoint 27.800000, which is way larger than all the other ones.

Comment: @psarka Confirming that. Removing this point eliminates the odd behavior. The standard deviation of sd without this point is 3.02, but 4.24 with this point. That explains the peaks at 3.02 and 4.24 (point not included in bootstrap; point included in bootstrap). The higher resonances are when this point is included multiple times.

Comment: @jwimberley why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @mdewey This was based on an observation by psarka which I don't want to take credit for.

Comment: @jwimberley Thank you so much for all of you involved. I never thought that 1 outlier can have so obvious 'resonator' effect. This is eye-opener for the small-sample bootstrap. Don't know how to mark those comments as the actual answer to the question.

Comment: I got back home and updated my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<strike>You might have a bug in your code, or the bootstrap library does something else than expected.</strike>

**Edit:**

After corrected data was provided, it became apparent that the pattern was caused by one outlier, with each peak corresponding to the different number of times the outlier was selected into a sample.

[image]

Comment: Ditto in R: After making the 21 element vector data in the obvious way, create a matrix of indices with `inds <- matrix(sample(21,10000*21,replace=TRUE),10000,21)` and then lookup the elements of data from each column and find the standard deviation with `hist(apply(inds,1,function(ind){sd(data[ind])}))`. There are not multiple peaks.

Comment: This answer explains and illustrates the problem very well, but provides no guidance or advices about what to do about it in practice.

Answer (score 8):

I am hesitant to put this down as an answer, but to me this seems to be caused by the small amount of datapoints you base your bootstrap on (21, correct me if I'm wrong).

To be more precise, to me it seems these **specific** 21 values, from which you sample, have only a few frequently possible standard deviations (the peaks in your histogram). If the base sample was larger and more diverse, the resulting histogram would be much smoother (and probably more alike the normal distribution you were expecting).

On a general note and assuming I in the right here, this is a good example to show bootstrapping does not solve the problems of having a small sample.

Comment: I like explanations like this, but I can't reproduce the result!

Comment: @NickCox You are absolutely right to point that out. I entered this answer without trying to replicate these results. As can be seen in Psarka's answer  (which I have immediately upvoted) there must have been some coding error. Hence, I've learned something as well (to try and replicate such a problem).

Comment: It's key too that bootstrap is necessarily dependent on the original data.

Comment: Of course it is, what point are you making?

Comment: Supporting you! Namely, arguing that artefacts are possible and that vigilance is needed.

Comment: Thanks! Even though my answer did not really solve the problem ... ;)

Comment: I also belive this is the right answer. A histogram of the data supports this explanation.

Comment: It's the right answer for the corrected question!